# Animated views resetting position after tapping textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have no storyboards and everything is programmatic. I have three TextFields, one of which is hidden(isHidden = true) and behind a login button, below the login button is a register button. If you tap the register button the login button slides down below the register button then the hidden textField shows using layoutSubViews() and setting isHidden to false.

My issue is that when tapping on any of the textfields the loginButton moves back to its original position. I have tried moving the textfield delegate to the viewcontroller, calling the setup() in willLayoutSubviews and didLayoutSubviews but the same thing still happens.

ViewController:

```
class WelcomeScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    private var currentUser: SplitterUser? {
        didSet {
            let nextViewController = MyBillsViewController()
            nextViewController.currentUser = self.currentUser
            present(nextViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }

    // swiftlint:disable line_length
    private let titleLogoLabel = TitleLabelLogo(frame: CGRect.zero, accessID: AccesID.titleLogoLabel)
    private let emailTextField = SplitterTextField(frame: CGRect.zero, accessID: AccesID.emailTextField)
    private let passwordTextField = SplitterTextField(frame: CGRect.zero, accessID: AccesID.passwordTextField)
    private let confirmPasswordTextField = SplitterTextField(frame: CGRect.zero, accessID: AccesID.confirmPasswordTextField)
    private let loginButton = SplitterButton(frame: CGRect.zero, accessID: AccesID.loginButton)
    private let registerButton = SplitterButton(frame: CGRect.zero, accessID: AccesID.registerButton)
    // swiftlint:enable line_length

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        view.backgroundColor = Color.mainBackground

        view.addSubview(titleLogoLabel)
        view.addSubview(emailTextField)
        view.addSubview(passwordTextField)
        view.addSubview(confirmPasswordTextField)
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        view.addSubview(registerButton)

        applyCommonLayoutFeaturesToAllViews()
        placeTitleLogoLabel()
        placeEmailTextField()
        placePasswordTextField()
        placePasswordConfirmationTextField()
        placeLoginButton()
        placeRegisterButton()
        setupKeyboard()
    }

    private func applyCommonLayoutFeaturesToAllViews() {
        view.subviews.forEach { subview in
            subview.pinToSuperview(edges: [.left, .right])
            subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }

    private func placeTitleLogoLabel() {
        let titleLogoLabelY = view.frame.height/4.5
        titleLogoLabel.pinTop(to: view, constant: titleLogoLabelY)
        titleLogoLabel.addHeightConstraint(with: Layout.titleLogoTextHeight)
    }

    private func placeEmailTextField() {
        emailTextField.centerYToSuperview()
        emailTextField.addHeightConstraint(with: Layout.textFieldHeight)
    }

    private func placePasswordTextField() {
        passwordTextField.pinTop(to: emailTextField,
                                 constant: Layout.textFieldHeight + Layout.spacer,
                                 priority: .required,
                                 relatedBy: .equal)
        passwordTextField.addHeightConstraint(with: Layout.textFieldHeight)
    }

    private func placePasswordConfirmationTextField() {
        confirmPasswordTextField.pinTop(to: passwordTextField,
                                        constant: Layout.textFieldHeight + Layout.spacer,
                                        priority: .required,
                                        relatedBy: .equal)
        confirmPasswordTextField.addHeightConstraint(with: Layout.textFieldHeight)
        confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden = true
    }

    private func placeLoginButton() {
        loginButton.pinTop(to: passwordTextField,
                           constant: Layout.textFieldHeight + Layout.spacer,
                           priority: .required,
                           relatedBy: .equal)
        loginButton.addHeightConstraint(with: Layout.buttonHeight)
        loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    private func placeRegisterButton() {
        registerButton.pinTop(to: loginButton,
                              constant: Layout.buttonHeight + Layout.spacer,
                              priority: .required,
                              relatedBy: .equal)
        registerButton.addHeightConstraint(with: Layout.buttonHeight)
        registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func registerButtonTapped() {
        if confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden {
            animateLoginButton()
        } else {
            registerNewUser()
        }
    }

    @objc private func loginButtonTapped() {
        if !confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden {
            animateLoginButton()
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
        } else {
            //segue to next vc
        }
    }

    private func animateLoginButton() {
        if confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden {
            moveLoginButtonDown()
        } else {
            moveLoginButtonUp()
        }
    }

    private func moveLoginButtonDown() {
        //Move loginButton down revealing confirmationPasswordTextView behind it
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.loginButton.frame.origin.y += Layout.loginButtonYMovement
            self.confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden = false
        })
    }

    private func moveLoginButtonUp() {
        //Move the loginButton up, when it has finished moving hide the confirmationPasswordTextView
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.loginButton.frame.origin.y -= Layout.loginButtonYMovement
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func setupKeyboard() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(sender:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                               object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(sender:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = Layout.welcomeScreenKeyboardMovement
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

TextField:

```
class SplitterTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var accessID: String!

    required init(frame: CGRect, accessID: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.accessID = accessID
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setup() {
        delegate = self
        backgroundColor = Color.textFieldBackground
        accessibilityIdentifier = accessID
        textAlignment = .center
        returnKeyType = .done
        placeholder = NSLocalizedString("\(accessID!)PlaceHolder", comment: "")
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

I am lost for what else to try. Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Comment: when pressing login button the position is reseting then animating yo umean?

Comment: no pressing login button and register button do as they should but when i tap a textfield after the login button has moved it resets back to its starting point

Comment: is there any edlegate function for textfield in your code other than textFieldShouldReturn ?

Comment: no that's the only function

Comment: Do you have any position setting in layoutSubviews ?

Comment: no none, thats all my code above apart from some irrelevant functions which ive deleted

Comment: is there any observer in Layout class? for keyboard show or hide or for any property to reset constraints. or any property which is declared with willset closure. see if there is any function called.

Comment: no layout is just a basic enum

Comment: but there are constants Layout.textFieldHeight being set.

Comment: it just an enum. `enum Layout { static let textHeight: CGFloat = 20 etc...}`

Comment: @WayneRumble try commenting keyboard observers see the effect.
adding their selectors code to textfield delegates didbegin and didend

Comment: didnt change anything, still does the same weird stuff. i thought that would stop it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150856/discussion-between-aadil-ali-and-wayne-rumble).

Answer (score 0):

Add a XIB file (so no Storyboard) which you type `WelcomeScreenViewController` as usual. Create the auto-layout constraints graphically (which is much easier).

Have a few of these constraints as outlets in your view controller code, which you then animate (together with the `alpha` of some subviews as needed).

I'm aware this is a completely different solution, but I think you're making things too complicated. `UIViewController`/XIB pairs are still a very nice and easy way to build UIs.

Comment: The whole point of the task(I've set to myself) is to not use them as the company i work for doesnt use any graphical interfacing. Thanks though

Comment: I see. Why don't they?

Comment: A few reasons, the one i can remember being that when multiple people work on a project having storyboards etc complicates github and makes solving issues harder to find as you have to scour through IB. i think

Comment: That's indeed a very good reason to not use Storyboards. I hate Storyboard for that and other reasons. But why don't they use code/XIB pairs for each screen and custom `UIView`? That works all fine when you are with multiple people.

Comment: Im not sure as i havent asked. When i do i will let you know, i may be wrong and they actually do, but i think theyb dont.

Answer (score 0):

You've set constraints on your views to lay them out. Auto layout uses the constraints to compute the frames of your views. Then you modify the frame of `loginButton` directly:

```
self.loginButton.frame.origin.y += Layout.loginButtonYMovement
```

The next time auto layout runs, it resets the frame of `loginButton` based on the constraints.

To move `loginButton`, you need to modify the constraints that set its frame. So for example you should save (in an instance variable) the top constraint you create in `placeLoginButton`. Then in `moveLoginButtonDown`, you can modify the saved constraint's constant, and in the animation block, call `self.view.layoutSubviews()`.

Comment: I dont quite understand how to implement what your saying, would you mind giving me a little help?